# Unable to deploy business-central.war with WildFly 25.0.0.Final version

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, businesscentral, wildfly-25

I have installed WildFly 25.0.0.Final running via docker container and this is hosted on an EC2 instance.
The below error messages encountered when deploying the business-central.war on HAL Management Console. Does it have anything to do with version incompatibility?

Business Central: business-central-7.74.1.Final-wildfly23.war

```
Kie Server: kie-server-7.74.1.Final-ee7.war

{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"business-central.war\".WeldStartService" => "Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 2 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KeyCloakUserManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCCredentialsUserManagementService(KeyCloakUserManager, KeyCloakGroupManager, CredentialsClientFactory, @Named UberfireRoleManager)
  at org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCCredentialsUserManagementService.<init>(KCCredentialsUserManagementService.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KeyCloakUserManager is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure from [Module \"deployment.business-central.war\" from Service Module Loader].

    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KeyCloakGroupManager with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 2 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCAdapterUserManagementService(KeyCloakUserManager, KeyCloakGroupManager, KCAdapterClientFactory, HttpServletRequest, @Named UberfireRoleManager)
  at org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KCAdapterUserManagementService.<init>(KCAdapterUserManagementService.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class org.uberfire.ext.security.management.keycloak.KeyCloakGroupManager is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure from [Module \"deployment.business-central.war\" from Service Module Loader].

    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.8.Final//org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
"}}
```

I am expecting to get the business central page and be able to login.